# Hypixel Skyblock Soul Eater

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-skyblock

The best enchanting book for damage is the [Soul Eater book](https://hypixel-skyblock.fandom.com/wiki/Soul_Eater). However there have been tons of debates and discussion about this book, along with tons of complaints about why it isnt working.

Its description:

> `Soul Eater is an Ultimate Enchantment that gains ❁ Damage from monsters killed and adds it on to the player's next hits.`

Its ability is:

> `Your weapon gains 2-10x the ❁ Damage of the latest monster killed and applies it on your next hit.`

Theroetically, it should rise up to infinite damage. However tons of people have complained it doesnt work. So, can someone provide a detailed explanation on how it really works, and how to use it properly?

Comment: The ability is poorly worded. I'm guessing the weapon's damage is only buffed by the *last* monster you killed, and the buffs don't stack when you kill multiple monsters.